# Looking for NodeJS hystrix like circuit breaker

Tags: node.js

I have one query to integrate this hystrixJS package in my app.
This is my express router call:

```
router.route('/users').post(userController.addUser);
```

The actual end point URL looks like: **http://localhost:3700/test/users**

I want to add circuit breaker for the above end point URL, in case of service down fall back method should be called. can anyone tell me how to do it.
Also i want to see the hystrixSSEStream as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Hystrixjs in a node app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836541/how-to-configure-hystrixjs-in-a-node-app)

Comment: Thanks for your response, That is for streaming and data metrics. I am looking for a straight forward configuration of my end points. Like we do it in Spring Java.